# instance of Dao class is not being initialized correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I want to load data from database into the RecyclerView using `Kotlin Coroutine`, but it does not load data at first launch, but when App is restarted it loads up data correctly. It seems there is something wrong in repository class:

NoteDao.kt is:

```
@Dao
interface NoteDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM NoteTable ORDER BY noteDate DESC")
    fun findAllNotes(): List<Note>

}
```

NoteRepository.kt

```
class NoteRepository(application: Application) {

    private var allNotes = MutableLiveData<List<Note>>()

    private val noteDAO = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).getNoteDao() // Issue is caused by this line because data is not assigned to noteDAO 

    fun getAllNotes(): MutableLiveData<List<Note>> {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val noteData = noteDAO.findAllNotes()
            allNotes.postValue(NoteData)
        }
        return allNotes   // it also returns empty List with size = 0
    }

}
```

adapter class is

```
class NoteAdapter(val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>() {

    private var allNotes: List<Note> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.Note_item, parent, false)
        return NoteHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentNote = allNotes[position]
        holder.title.text = currentNote.title
        holder.date.text = DateUtils.getDate(Date(currentNote.date))

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return allNotes.size
    }

    fun addNotes(allNotes: List<Note>) {
        this.allNotes = allNotes
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class NoteHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var title: LabelTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title)
        var date: LabelTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_date)
    }

}
```

and ViewModel is

```
class NoteViewModel(
    application: Application
): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var repository = NoteRepository(application)

    private var _allNotes = repository.getAllNotes()

    val allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>>
        get() = _allNotes
}
```

and lastly it is attached in MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private lateinit var mNoteViewModel: NoteViewModel
    private lateinit var mNoteAdapter: NoteAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)    

        mNoteAdapter = NoteAdapter(this)

        mNoteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
        mNoteViewModel.allNotes.observe(
            this, Observer {
                Log.e("MAIN_ACTIVITY", "Called...") // it is printed in Log but data is not recieved from repository
                mNoteAdapter.addNotes(it)
            }
        )

        rv_log.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        mNoteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        rv_log.adapter = mNoteAdapter
    }

}
```

that all is not loading and displaying data in `RecyclerView`.

Comment: add  `mNoteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` below `mNoteAdapter.addNotes(it)` line

Comment: Dao instance is null at `private val noteDAO = NoteDatabase.getDatabase(application).getNoteDao()` line

Comment: Are you using Room? If so you Dao class needs to extend from RoomDatabase

Comment: Yes it is extending RoomDatabase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is with `getAllNotes()` means `CoroutineScope` is not working correctly. You should use [Flow API](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/) and change Dao methods to

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM NoteTable ORDER BY noteDate DESC")
fun findAllNotes(): Flow<List<Note>>
```

after this you must change NoteRepository class and put `init` block as:

```
init {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
         val noteData = noteDAO.findAllNotes()
         noteData.collect{ // it is related to Flow API
             allNotes.postValue(it)
         }
    }
}
```

and just return `allNotes` in `getAllNotes()`

```
fun getAllNotes(): MutableLiveData<List<Note>> {            
    return allNotes 
}
```

now you must check if it works?

Comment: Saved my day! it works like a charm, but why Flow<T> is never ever used in any tutorials this before??

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with the accepted answer. It is not an issue with `CoroutineScope`.

The reason why the original code is returning an empty `List` is because you are not declaring the DAO function as a `suspend` function. Since `getAllNotes()` is not a `suspend` function, it will not suspend the calling coroutine until Room returns with a result and hence returns an empty list.

I will also suggest to use `asLiveData()` if you are trying to convert a `Flow` to a `LiveData`.

Comment: I am pretty new to the world of Kotlin and coroutines I tried to declare `getAllNotes()` with `suspend` but it never worked, so the accepted answer worked for me. I realize that the accepted answer must to have been down voted at least in this case where it worked for me.